# Binary search not working for n = 1, 2

Tags: c++, search, binary-search

This is my code for binary search, and `n = no of elements in array`

```
// Binary Search
// BUG: not working for n = 2

#include <iostream>

int main() {

    const int n = 1;
    int newlist[n];

    std::cout << "Enter " << n;
    std::cout << " elements in increasing order:\n";

    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        std::cin >> newlist[i];
    }

    int pos = 0, num;
    std::cout << "Enter number:\n";
    std::cin >> num;
    std::cout << '\n';


    int imin = 0, imax = n-1;
    int imid = (n - 1)/2;

    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {

        imid = (imin + imax) / 2;

        if( newlist[imid] == num ) {
            pos = imid;
        }

        else if( newlist[imid] < num ) {
            imin = imid+1;
        }

        else {
            imax = imid-1;
        }
    }

    if( pos != 0 ) {
        std::cout << "Found at " << pos+1;
    }

    else {
        std::cout << "Not found!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It does work for `n > 2`, but fails to give correct output for `n <= 2`, ie, gives `Not found!` output even for elements that were found.

I think one way would be to have a separate implementation for `n <= 2`, but that will become cumbersome! Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @PaulR This is a program which perfectly compiled using both clang++ and g++. Therefore the **problem is in logic, which can't be found out using a debugger!**

Comment: If you had stepped through the code in a debugger then your logic bug would have been immediately obvious.

Comment: @samjoe, Debuggers are extremely useful in finding problems in logic. In fact, since you need an executable to run in a debugger, how would a debugger help with problems where compilation fails? Answer: it wouldn't.

Comment: Please guide me how to use a debugger? I have gdb on my system already, but its frustrating me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your pos operator to -1 rather than 0. 0 represents your first index and since you output that the element has not been found for pos == 0 condition, your code is failing. You should set pos to -1 initially and check that itself for not found condition, if an element is found at pos = 0, that means the element exists at the first index.

Answer (score 3):

First `pos` equal to `0` is correct value. Therefore set `pos` to `-1` at the beginning and compare to `-1` (or more commonly `>= 0`) when checking whether it was found.

Secondly, there are few items that should be changed because right now it's not that much binary search:

1. There is no reason to initialize `mid` before the loop, it's just temporary variable with the scope in loop block.
2. The condition for exiting the search is `min > max`, you don't need any additional counter, as it would run the loop always `n` times even if the value didn't exist. So change to `while (min <= max) { ...`
3. Last but not least, once you find the item, exit the loop immediately by `break` statement.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think a for-loop is the control structure to go for here, because you want to finish when you've either found the correct item or when imin and imax are non-sensical.

In the implementation given, you don't even stop the loop when you have found the item and just confirm the found item "n-(number of iterations until item was found)" times.

Furthermore, with C++ arrays and vectors being 0-based, having position == 0 as the marker for "not found" is a bad idea; you could instead use an item from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits, or n (since the indices go from 0 to n-1).

In theory, you could use pointer arithmetic to make your array 1-based, and I am assuming you haven't; I wouldn't recommend it. However, you're code snipped is missing the actual definition of the list.